# WPF ComboBox to select Font with DataTemplate and CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, datatemplate, code-behind

I need to program a comboBox that displays Fonts and each one stylized. As this image:

[image]

I am constrained to do it by code-behind, not xaml.

My xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="_08_Binding_DataTemplate_CodeBehind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="lstFonts" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

and c#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CollectionViewSource c = new CollectionViewSource();
        c.Source = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;
        c.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Source", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        lstFonts.ItemsSource = c.View;


        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = lstFonts;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath( "SelectedValue" );


        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(ComboBox));

        FrameworkElementFactory sp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        sp.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
        sp.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);

        FrameworkElementFactory holder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        holder.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
        holder.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty, b);

        sp.AppendChild(holder);
        dt.VisualTree = sp;

        lstFonts.ItemTemplate = dt;
    }
}
```

I have tried many variants but have not been successful. I guess the binding is failing but do not know how to fix it.
The most I've gotten has been linked with the selected source, but then change all the elements of the list, as in the following image.

[image]

I do not know how to program this binding, so that each item in the list to refer to himself.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to do it on XAML, try this below,

### XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="lstFonts" ItemsSource="{x:StaticFonts.SystemFontFamilies}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource item}" >
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontFamily="{Binding }"/>    
    </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.Resources>
<ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said I am required to program it on C#, not xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it by loading xaml markups, but I would like to program it only with C# code, without xaml markups. Thanks.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CollectionViewSource c = new CollectionViewSource();
        c.Source = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;
        c.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Source", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        lstFonts.ItemsSource = c.View;
        lstFonts.ItemTemplate = getDataTemplateFromXAML();
    }

    private DataTemplate getDataTemplateFromXAML()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">");
        sb.Append("<StackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing=\"True\">");
        sb.Append("<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding }\" FontFamily=\"{Binding }\"/>");
        sb.Append("</StackPanel>");
        sb.Append("</DataTemplate>");

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);

        DataTemplate retVal = XamlReader.Load(xr) as DataTemplate;
        return retVal;
    }
```